# Second form submitting overrides mongo database in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I've got two forms that i sumbit onclick of one button at the same time.
The problem is, that only the second form inputs are written to database.
It's like always the second form. I tried to change the order of submit() calls and always inputs from the second call form are written to database. 
Any suggestions?

saving methods:

```
app.post('/saveInScopeStatuses', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var scopes = req.body.scope;
    var collection = db.get('scopestatuses');
    var total = scopes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i<total; i++){
        var scope = scopes.pop();
        collection.update({"status": {
                $eq: scope}
        }, {
            $set: {
                inscope: true
            }
        },
        {upsert: true});
    }
});

 app.post('/saveOutScopeStatuses', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var scopes = req.body.scope;
    var collection = db.get('scopestatuses');
    var total = scopes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i<total; i++){
        var scope = scopes.pop();
        collection.update({"status": {
                $eq: scope}
        }, {
            $set: {
                inscope: false
            }
        },
        {upsert: true});
    }
});
```

forms: 
`<form id="inScopeForm" method="post" action="saveInScopeStatuses">
                            {{#each scopes}}
                            {{#if status}}
                            <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="                            {{status}}"/>
                            {{/if}}
                            {{/each}}
                            </form>
                            <form id="outScopeForm" method="post" action="saveOutScopeStatuses">
                            {{#each scopes}}
                            {{#unless status}}
                            <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="{{status}}"/>
                            {{/unless}}
                            {{/each}}
                            </form>`